# How to set table format as default in google cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

When I try to list anything, my result is not grouped as a table ( as in the video). Each region is listed separately with its descriptions. Something like this

---

NAME: us-west3

CPUS: 0/24

DISKS_GB: 0/4096

ADDRESSES: 0/8

RESERVED_ADDRESSES: 0/8

STATUS: UP

TURNDOWN_DATE:

NAME: us-west4

CPUS: 0/24

DISKS_GB: 0/4096

ADDRESSES: 0/8

RESERVED_ADDRESSES: 0/8

STATUS: UP

TURNDOWN_DATE:

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```bash
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader False
```

And then repeat the command.

Comment: Also, some commands support `--format=table` and  `--format="[box]"`. For more table options: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats

Comment: Thank you. "accessibility/screen_reader" worked. I actually tried format=table command. It didn't work.